# Mazda 3 2015 ac not working

Tags: ac, mazda, mazda-3

My Mazda 3 2015 ac is blowing hot air and my radiator fans aren’t turning on. What could be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The fans aren't turning on at all? Is the car overheating as well, or are the fans just not coming on when you turn the AC on? There could be a lot of reasons why it's not coming on. You might want to check your fuses first ... the ones underhood.

Comment: These may or may not be related issues.  Why do you think the fans should be turning on?  Is the engine overheating?  What about the AC compressor, is it running?  Have you checked the high-side/low-side pressures?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If fuses are fine and the radiator fans aren't running when ac is used, the most likely  reason for loss of ac/fan cooling is a leak releasing refrigerant in a sealed system. Virtually every vehicle turns on cooling fans to force airflow thru hot ac condenser coils and hot radiator otherwise overheating will occur in hot/humid local traffic. A low/high pressure sensor detects loss of refrigerant and sends a signal to the engine computer. The ecm disables power to the compressor and cooling fan(s) since the compressor isn't running. Coolant temps are still monitored to cycle fan cooling.

Comment: @FDryer -- seems like this would make a good answer.